# Regular expression to match flattened property names

Tags: regex

I have specific flattened property names that I need to validate. Basically, what's valid is alpha-numeric string that can be followed by an array index ([4] for example), but doesn't have to be. If it's followed by a next word, then it has to be joined by a dot.

To illustrate, some of the examples that would be valid are:

```
parent[0].child
parent.child
parent.child1.list[0].child2
parent[500].child
parent0.child
par50ent.child
parent[0].child1[20].child[0]
```

And some invalid examples are

```
parent..child
parent[].child
parent[1a].child
parent[a].child
.parent
parent.
```

I don't know much about regular expressions, so what I came up with is this following line:

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})(\[[0-9]{1,}\]){0,1}){1}((\.){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})(\[[0-9]{1,}\]){0,1}){0,}
```

While this does work, it's just too verbose. There has to be a nicer, shorter way to write this.

Comment: Is it for pcre/java? If atomic groups are supported, another idea: [`^\b(?>\.?\w+(?:\[\d+\])?)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/AEo1V8/1) (it works without, but would become considerably slower).

Comment: @bobblebubble It is for Java. I don't know what any of those are, but thanks for the suggestion, I'll research it a bit. I'm using anubhava's suggestion currently as I'm fine with underscores in names as well.

Comment: Thanks for response! Yea anubhava's one is efficient... regarding my pattern: If you want to match such as `parent[0][1].child`, change the [last quantifier `?` *zero or one* to `*` for *any amount*](https://regex101.com/r/leAxDX/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble I think I'll avoid multi-dimensional lists for now, but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex to match only valid cases:

```sh
^\w+(?:\[\d+])?(?:\.\w+(?:\[\d+])?)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P65eU7/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:\[\d+])?`: Match optional `[<digits>]` part
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `\.`: Match a dot
  - `\w+(?:\[\d+])?`: Match a word followed by optional `[<digits>]`
- `)*`: End non-capture group. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `$`: End

You may use this regex if you want to allow `parent[0][1].child` as well:

```
^\w+(?:\[\d+])*(?:\.\w+(?:\[\d+])*)*$
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that letters are English ones (`A..Z` or `a..z`) while digits are `0..9`, you can try

```
^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*(?:\[[0-9]+\])*(?>\.[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*(?:\[[0-9]+\])*)*$
```

pattern:

```
^               - anchor, string start 
[A-Za-z]+       - starts from letter
[A-Za-z0-9] *   - can contain zero or more letters or digits
(?:\[[0-9]+\])* - can end by zero or more [digits] indexers

(?>\. ...)*     - followed by zero or mo costructions each of them
                  starts from dot . and has syntax equals to the one above 
$               - anchor, string end
```

[Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/hE2vaN/2)

**Edit:** please, note [atomic group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `(?> ...)` to prevent catastrophic bactracking (see The fourth bird's comment below)

Comment: (the nested quantifier in the repeating group might lead to catastrophic backtracking if there is no match https://regex101.com/r/55EgcQ/1)

Comment: @The fourth bird: thank you! Nice catch

Comment: Voting for this as well as it accepts such as `parent[0][1].child` no idea if that was mentioned by OP, but certainly it makes sense!